# Selecting an html <object> using JQuery and adding a <div class> to it

Tags: jquery, html

I have an rss feed that spits out plain html so I want to be able to select an
`<object>` and add a class to it in order to be able to style it.

This is the jquery code I wrote but it seems to not be working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var vid = $("select[name=object]");
    $(“vid”).addClass(“youtube”);
});
```

I am relatively new to using Jquery.

EDIT:
Figured it out:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    vid = $("object");
    vid.addClass("youtube");
}
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: why not just use `$("select[name=object]").addClass("youtube");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var vid = $("select[name='object']");
    vid.addClass(“youtube”);
});
```

try this. You already have the jquery object just call addClass off of it. Also I put single quotes around the value of your name attribute, not sure if this matters but it is good code convension none the less

Comment: for some reason that wasn't working but this worked
    `$(document).ready(function(){
        vid = $("object");
        vid.addClass("youtube");
    }`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var vid = $("select[name=object]");
    vid.addClass(“youtube”);
});
```

**vid is already a jQuery object.**

you can just call jquery methods right on it